# Free Wordpress theme for an intranet tutorial site

Tags: themes, theme-recommendation

I work for a research oriented company and hence a lot of new facts and ways of going about work are found everyday. We want to consolidate all our understandings and categorize them as tutorials on our company intranet which some writers (who are authorized to do so) can update.

I need a comprehensive theme that is elegant, creative and simple to manage which a customizable menu and is apt for a multi-discipline tutorial intranet site. Also one that comes pre-customized for a tutorial oriented site so that i don't have to find too many plug-ins to make it useful.

some theme like [this site](http://net.tutsplus.com/), though more spacious for text

Answer (score 1):

You should look for a theme on the [WordPress themes directory](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) and see if there's one that fits your needs. They're all free and the [tag filter](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/tag-filter/) let's you search for themes with a certain functionality, including customizable menu.

I think some of the requirements are pretty subjective, so you could consider hiring a WordPress theme developer. Other than that, just browse the free themes catalogs see if you can find a good one.

If you're asking for theme suggestions, I personally don't know what the requirement would be for it to be tutorial oriented, but you'll have to get this functionality via plugins.

Answer (score 1):

It's not free, but I'm impressed with [Knowledgebase](http://www.wpbundle.com/2011/new-theme-knowledgebase-with-images/) by WPBundle, sold through Woo Themes.  It has a custom taxonomy organized by Questions, Documents, and Resources.

Answer (score 0):

Other than realize yourself the theme, you can customize some free theme.

Here there are two that are easily customizable, without having to touch HTML.

1. [Arras Theme](http://www.arrastheme.com/)
2. [Caribou](http://demo.spectacu.la/caribou/)
3. [Inove](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/inove)

They have support for tags and category, that are great if you have tutorials on different topics.